# AngularJS - get the link in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Good morning, this one is the only question that is similar in nature to mine, but unfortunately, it did not help me find an answer, so your help is highly appreciated.

I have the following snippet of HTML code:

```
<li class="first-page" ng-click="selectFirst()" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">
    First
</li>
```

I want to adjust the `<li>` so that it shows a link. In the directive's link function I included one more function:

```
function getPaginationLink($location) {
        var linkToPage = $location.$$url;
        console.log($location.$$url);
        return linkToPage;
    }
```

and slightly changed the html, in the following way:

```
<li class="first-page" ng-click="selectFirst()" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">
    <a ng-onload="getPaginationLink($location)" ng-href="{{ linkToPage }}">
        First
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linkToPage` is not linked with the model anywhere in your controller's `getPaginationLink` function and using it in `href="{{linkToPage}}"` would be undefined.

If you just want to use the returned in value of `getPaginationLink` in `href`, just use

```
<li class="first-page" ng-click="selectFirst()" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">
<a ng-init="url = getPaginationLink($location)" ng-href="{{url}}">First</a>
</li>
```

Here is an example snippet

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){

$scope.getr = function(){
  return "URL"
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<li class="first-page" ng-click="selectFirst()" onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">
<a ng-init="url = getr()" ng-href="{{url}}">First</a>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: While it perfectly works in the case of your code, it does not show any result in my case. Thank you anyway, I see a mistake that I made.

Comment: what's the issue you're facing with your code using this ?

Comment: The issue is that I can't get it working, I can't get the url shown when am pointing on "First" with the mouse.

Comment: you don't need to pass that as function argument. Just inject it in controller and you'll be able to use it

Comment: Finally, I managed to get a result by using your hints, thank you. Now, one more question on top: how could I inject the $location service into the getUrl function: 

     angular.module('AppCore')
     .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, 
     $location){
     $scope.getUrl = function($scope, $location){
      console.log($location);
      // return $location.$$url;
      return "sometexttoseeifitworks.org";
     }
}])

Comment: I do get the link when I am mousing over the "First" clause, however, it looks like the location service does not work, it returns "undefined" despite me injecting the dependency in the controller

Comment: do not pass this in function. Just use it inside of it after injecting in controller. Something like 
`$scope.getUrl = function(){ console.log($location.host())`

Comment: Thank you George! I got the result I was looking for, your assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to know that :) Thanks